# Prevent double submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a submit button:

```
<div class="submitForm">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="SAVE" class="greyishBtn" onclick ="if(!DW_CheckIfImagesInBuffer())
{return confirm('No images');
}else{
 btnUpload_onclick(2)}"/>  </div>
```

I'm tryng to to prevent submit form twice disabling button in this way:

```
else{
 btnUpload_onclick(2) this.disabled=true; this.value='Please Wait...';}
```

Button when submit change to **Please Wait**, but form is not submitted.

Any help?

TKS ALL

Comment: Missing semicolon: `btnUpload_onclick(2);`<- there!

Comment: Tks  elclanrs, but not send yet...

Comment: your problem's probably in here ... `if(!DW_CheckIfImagesInBuffer())`

Comment: This may be obvious, but is the button actually inside a `form`?

Comment: Mathletics, if I remove this.disabled=true; this.value='Please Wait...'; form work correctly...

Comment: @user2307958: How do you check it's "not submitted"? And provide your **real** code. The one from the question is syntactically incorrect and should produce errors in js console

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `;` in the else statement

```
btnUpload_onclick(2) this.disabled=true; this.value='Please Wait...';
               //   ^ Here             ^ Like this
```

Change to

```
btnUpload_onclick(2); this.disabled=true; this.value='Please Wait...';
```